# Keep getting "MethodNotAllowedHttpException" when trying to display a page redirected from an external URL

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to reach to my local page from an external URL, which is from a payment gateway, based on the return URL parameter. However, when I link it back to my page, I keep getting the "MethodNotAllowedHttpException" error. Below are my codes;

Order Controller:

```
public function kiplestatus(Request $request, $id) {
        dd($request);
        $showFeedbackForm = true;

        $order = \App\Order::where('id', $id)->get();
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/order/kiplestatus/{id}', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@kiplestatus',
    'as' => 'order.kiplestatus',
    'middleware' => ['auth','verify.mobile.no','agent'],
]);
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: are you sure callback method is ```get```? try ```any``` method instead of ```get``` and check it : ```Route::any(```

Comment: It "works" if i use any/post, however, instead of going to my /order/kiplestatus/id url, it redirects to my home url.  I'm kind of confused as to why it would do this

Comment: maybe because of middlewares that you use, for example i think auth method caused, its better to remove middleware and check it again

Comment: still getting the same behavior..

Comment: I think the path for callback ```/order/kiplestatus/{id}``` is not correct check payment document because if callback method is post so it doesnt response {id} in url

Comment: This is the only thing the document says; "The return parameters will be sent to your ord_returnURL, which you will provide when initiate the payment." I have already set my ord_returnURL to /order/kiplestatus/{id}

Comment: how do you define this route as payment callback?

Comment: `$query = [
            'ord_date' => $dueDate,
            'ord_totalamt' => $cart_total,
            'ord_gstamt' => 0.00,
            'ord_shipname' => $user['name'],
            'ord_mercref' => $ord_mercref,
            'ord_mercID' => $merchantid,
            'ord_returnURL' => 'http://local.site.com/order/kiplestatus/'. $ord_mercref,
            'merchant_hashvalue' => $key,
            'key' => $key2
        ];`

Comment: Those are the fields to be sent to the payment gateway, ord_returnURL is the URL they redirect to after a successful payment. What they said in the documentation and email was that they will return parameters to me upon redirection in post format?

Comment: so i found out the issue, for some weird reason, the issue was actually a csrf token mismatch, and by removing csrf from the link, it works fine. I do not know why this happened and how laravel didn't detect it until i checked via mailtrap, but yeah.